# .Rmd file failing to knit to pdf due to filepath error in Mac

Tags: r, r-markdown

My desktop version of `rmarkdown` does not appear to be able to knit a pdf from an .`Rmd` file when an image reference is included whereas the *same* .`Rmd` document on my laptop knits to pdf just fine.

I am using an image reference of the form:

```
![Name given to the image](Users/myname/image/Dropbox/foldername/imagename.png)
```

The .`Rmd` script knits fine on my desktop when the image is removed and, as I said, knits fine with the same image reference on my laptop. Therefore I assume it must be filepath issue. But the file is saved in the same place in a linked dropbox account on both computers so the filepath is exactly the same.

The error message below is what I got (with actual filepaths changed)

> pandoc: Could not find image
>   `/Users/myname/image/Dropbox/foldername/imagename.png, skipping...
>
> ! Missing $ inserted.
>         
>                        $
>       l.307 ...dername/imagename.png}
>
> pandoc: Error producing PDF from TeX source
>       Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
>
> Execution halted

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: maybe no file in the end catalog , maybe c:/ before path

Comment: Thanks Mateusz but the file is there (it finds it on my laptop no problem). And c:/ does not apply to Macs.

Comment: ok, one more thing use "\" instead of "/",